# Why can't friend function be recognized with using directive vs enclosing in namespace?

Tags: c++, header-files, friend

Why can't the friend `operator<<` be recognized when defined in the cpp file and a using directive? 
I have in header file, `game.h`

```
namespace uiuc {

class Game {
public:
  Game();
  void solve();

  friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, Game & game);

private:
  std::vector<Stack> stacks;
};
```

And in my cpp file, `game.cpp`:

```
#include "game.h"

using namespace  uiuc;
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, Game & game) {
  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < game.stacks.size(); ++i) {
    os << "Stack [" << i << "]: " << game.stacks[i] << std::endl;
  }

  return os;
}
```

The error I get is:

```
g++ -std=c++1z -g -Wfatal-errors -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -MMD -MP  -c game.cpp
game.cpp:5:38: fatal error: 'stacks' is a private member of 'uiuc::Game'
  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < game.stacks.size(); ++i) {
                                     ^
./game.h:17:22: note: declared private here
  std::vector<Stack> stacks;
                     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Makefile:18: game.o] Error 1
```

This worked when the friend function was defined in the header file. I decided to move it since I was getting a linker error for a duplicate symbol for the same method so I decided to see what would happen if I moved the function definition to the cpp file. What am I missing? However when I enclose the definition within the `namespace uiuc`, it removes this error and I am back to the linker error. The linker error is **NOT** what this question is about.

Why can't the compiler not realize that this is a friend function and so can access the private variables?

Comment: The fix is simple: Just enclose your definition in `namespace uiuc {` and `}`. IMHO, that's very usual. ;-) I stronly believe the operator definition is placed in global namespace (ignoring the `using namespace uiuc` and the `friend` declaration). Hence, the `friend` declaration in `uiuc::Game` is unrelated.

Comment: You cannot define a function in a namespace using `using`. If you had `namespace uiuc {void foo();}` then you can't define it with `using namespace uiuc; void foo() {...}`

Comment: FYI: [SO: Why would a struct need a friend function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52370542/7478597)

Comment: If you want to keep it in the header file which means stopping the duplicate include warning simply make the function inline.

Comment: @andre, inline solves the issue. But from what I have read, it is up to the compiler to decide to inline the function. What if it doesn't?

Comment: @heretoinfinity The `inline` keyword has nothing directly to do with whether functions are inlined. The actual meaning of the `inline` keyword is related to whether function definitions can (or must) be repeated in multiple translation units. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions first declared as `friend` in a class are placed in the enclosing namespace, so the function you want to define must be defined in the `uiuc` namespace.

You might be under assumption that if you use `using namespace uiuc;` new declarations/definitions will be placed into the `uiuc` namespace, but that is not the case. `using namespace` only affects the lookup of names, not where declarations/definitions are placed.

Therefore the function you are defining at the moment is `operator<<(std::ostream & os, uiuc::Game & game)` in the *global* namespace scope (which is not a `friend` of `uiuc::Game`), not `operator<<(std::ostream & os, Game & game)` in the `uiuc` namespace.

So you need to open the namespace properly:

```
#include "game.h"

namespace uiuc {
  std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, Game & game) {
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < game.stacks.size(); ++i) {
      os << "Stack [" << i << "]: " << game.stacks[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return os;
  }
}
```

Also, regarding the linker error: If you define the `friend` function *outside* the class definition and you don't specify it as `inline`, then it will be a *non-inline function*, meaning that there may be only *one* definition for it in only *one* translation unit. This typically precludes putting the definition in the header, because the header is usually included in multiple translation units.

If you define the function *inside* the class body or declare it with the `inline` keyword, then it will be an *inline function*, meaning that it has to be defined in every translation unit using it, which usually means that the definition must be placed in the header file.